# In the following code, does pop() actually removes the item from the array 'num' or the item still exists inside the 'num'?

Tags: c++, data-structures, stack

Does pop function really removes the item from the array, it just changes the pointing index?

```
int STACK::pop()
    {
        int temp;
        if(isEmpty())
            return -9999;
        temp=num[top];
        --top;
        return temp;
     }
```

Comment: You can't remove element from array. But stack is different than array.

Comment: what is `num`  ? Pedantically it is quite possible that the code removes an element from `num`, if its `operator[]` would have some odd implementation.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number `it is quite possible that the code removes an element from num` it's possible only if num is not an array, unlike implied by the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the element isn't removed from the array. It isn't possible to add or remove elements of an array. Arrays have constant number of elements through their lifetime.